# very basic integral identites

Tags: integration

im really confused about how to use the Riemann conditions..
 how to proof these identitis?

$\int^{cb}_{ca} f(x){dx}$  = $\int^{b}_{a} c·f(cx)dx$

$\int^{b}_{a} f(x){dx}$  = $\int^{b+c}_{a+c} ·f(x-c)dx$

Comment: In the first case substitute $y=cx$ which gives $dy=c\cdot dx$ and in the second substitute $y=x-c$ with $dy=dx$.

Comment: im not allowed to use that so freely, i need to proof the isentity, usuing riemann conditions for integraitions

Comment: I'd bet my balls that this problem arises before integration by substituion.

Comment: @eyal: Oh, so you're working from the raw definition of a Riemann integral?

Comment: yep.thank you for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider a Riemann sum for $\int_{ca}^{cb} f(x)\,dx$: $$\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)\cdot(x_k-x_{k-1}),$$ write $x_k=ct_k$, where $t_0$, $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ is a partition of $[a,b]$. Use a similar rewrite for the other integral.

Answer (score 1):

Take $c>0$; the other cases are similar. There is an obvious correspondence between partitions of $[a,b]$ and partitions of $[ca,cb]$: if
$$\mathcal{D} = \{ a=x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b \}$$
is a partition of $[a,b]$ then
$$\mathcal{D}' = \{ ca=x'_0 < x'_1 < \cdots < x'_n = cb \}$$
where $x'_i=cx_i$, is a partition of $[ca,cb]$; and the other direction is obvious.

The upper sum on $[ca,cb]$ is then given by
$$\begin{align} U(f(x);\mathcal{D}') &= \sum_{i=1}^n (x'_i-x'_{i-1}) \sup_{t \in [x'_i,x'_{i-1}]} f(t)\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n (cx_i-cx_{i-1}) \sup_{t \in [cx_i,cx_{i-1}]} f(t) \\ &= c \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1}) \sup_{s \in [x_i, x_{i-1}]} f(cs)\\
&= c \cdot U(f(cx);\mathcal{D})\end{align}$$
The lower sums do the same thing, i.e. $L(f(x);\mathcal{D}') = c \cdot L(f(cx); \mathcal{D})$. [By the way, I've included the dummy variable in the notation for upper and lower sums to distinguish between $f$ and $f \circ (c \times -)$.]

Since the above correspondence between partitions is exact, the supremum over all $\mathcal{D}$ is exactly the supremum over all $\mathcal{D}'$; and this means that the integrals must transform accordingly.

The case of transferring between $[a,b]$ and $[a+c,b+c]$ is similar (and easier).

Comment: im sorry i forgot to write the c is not necceseraly > 0

Comment: @eyal: I know; I thought I'd leave the case $c<0$ to you. (It's not hard; and in fact it follows by just considering the case $c=-1$ separately and then applying the result for the positive case.)

Comment: allright i think ill figure that one out myself.
thank you!

Comment: got it . thanks you so much.